# Does the difficulty you play on have any effect on gwent?

Tags: the-witcher-3

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222716/saints-row-the-third-does-the-difficulty-level-affect-the-mini-games-snatch) question got me wondering.

Does the difficulty you play on have any effect on the difficulty of gwent or other mini-games?

Answer (score 12):

I don't have an official source for it, but i played the game on two difficulties (bst and now death march) and the cpu doesn't seem to use other tactics or different cards.

Also, in previous Witcher games, minigames (Dice poker or arm wrestling) were unaffected by the difficulty of the game since every opponent already had his own difficulty level. I think this is still the case in Witcher 3.

Answer (score 4):

The current answer is outdated. The new patches have added a Gwent difficulty that is independent from the difficulty of the rest of the game.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading the other answer, but it sounds like it's already saying what you've said (that game difficulty does not affect gwent difficulty since each NPC has their own built-in difficulty).

Comment: You are correct, except now there is a specific Gwent difficulty selection you can make. According to the date in which the answer was submitted, the specific Gwent difficulty was not implemented at that time.